# safari 14.1.2 - can not print a pdf use printjs

Tags: safari, printjs

I try to use PrintJs and print a PDF file in safari(14.1.2), but when I preview the print file in dialog, I got a empty page. help me!

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: const pdfFile = new Blob(['myFile'], {
        type: 'application/pdf',
 });
const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile);
printJS(pdfUrl);